# Linux PuTTY - automate su for password related issue

Tags: linux, putty, su

I am connecting to a server via PuTTY as follows:

```
putty.exe -ssh user@host -pw password -noagent -m commands.txt
```

After that I have to use:

```
su someUser
```

It will ask for a password - I have put this inside command.txt but it's not working.

How can I automate the su command (including password) in a single line that I can place inside command.txt? Or perhaps there is a different approach?

I don't want to use sudo or execute and all. I tried with:

```
echo password | su someUser
```

However piping in this way did not work.

Comment: Why don't you log in as 'someuser' in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

You can disable password questions by adding a script/program specific line in the /etc/sudoers file:
yourusername ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/whatever

Comment: For unexplained reasons the OP won't use sudo, though. Your answer is correct, but he's not interested.

Answer (score 0):

Is it vital for you to use su and save the password in a file? If not use a different approach, becasue:

```
$ su << LOL
> secretpassword
> LOL
su: must be run from a terminal

$ echo secretpassword|su - 
su: must be run from a terminal
```

You would be better off with ssh keys: [Quck ssh-keys intro](http://genja.org/wordpress/2009/10/quick-ssh-keys-intro/)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you want to use `sudo`? su will always ask for the password using terminal capabilities, so you'd need to create a pseudo-terminal to communicate with it. `expect` can do that for you.

However, I think that the "proper" way to solve this is either using a suid executable owned by a specific user, or even better - using properly configured `sudo`.

Comment: `suid` is rarely, if ever a good idea.

Comment: @new123456 sudo with NOPASSWD, available for all is pretty much suid equivalent. Still better than expect + su. Of course properly configured sudo is the best choice here.