# Plink is not switching user using su command

Tags: linux, ssh, putty, su, plink

I am connecting to a server via plink as follows:

```
plink -ssh -l username -pw password example.host.com -m C:\Putty\input.txt > C:\Putty\output.txt
```

input.txt contains

```
whoami
su - newsuser
whoami
```

output.txt contains

```
username
username
```

SU is not working via plink.

If try the same command in putty its working fine and getting the output as **"newsuser"**.

[Linux PuTTY - automate su for password related issue](https://superuser.com/questions/298476/linux-putty-automate-su-for-password-related-issue)

i tried the above solution but its not working for me.

thanks

Answer (score 3):

First, it does not work the way you think.

The commands in the script are executed in sequence. The `su` (had it succeeded) would execute an interactive shell session and wait for user input (commands). Only once the `su` exists, the second `whoami` runs (showing `username`).

---

Anyway, your `su` does not work indeed.

First, the `su` for sure outputs some error message. What is that? You capture only a standard output in your commands. Capture an error output too (`2>&1`). It most likely fails, because `su` may need an interactive terminal, while Plink with `-m` switch uses non-interactive terminal by default. Adding [`-t` switch](https://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-cmdline-pty) helps in this case.

---

Note that automating `su` is generally a bad idea. If you need to run some commands that require root privileges, a better solution is to associate a dedicated private key with the commands in `sudoers` file. And then use `sudo` and private key in the Plink.

See also [Allowing automatic command execution as root on Linux using SSH](https://superuser.com/q/1481318/213663).